# Python : Checking the length of pandas column value for if condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python program which process multiple files. Each file have customer id column based on department. Some file has 8 digit customer id and some have 9 digit customer id.
I need to do this

```
if length of customer id column value is == 8:
    input_file['customer_id'] = input_file['customer_id'].str[0:2] + '-' + input_file['customer_id'].str[2:8]
if length of customer id column value is == 9:
    input_file['customer_id'] = 'K' + '-' + input_file['customer_id'].str[0:3] + '-' + input_file['customer_id'].str[3:8]
```

Input

```
id cusotmerid
1  89898988
2  898989889
```

Output

```
id cusotmerid
1  89-898988
2  K-898-989889
```

How can I achieve it. Unable to find anything which can do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `np.select`. In order to check the length of the string, you have to first make sure that the column's format is a string, hence `.astype(str)`. Then, you can use `.apply(lambda x: len(x) == condition)` to to return a result based on the condition:

```
import numpy as np
input_file['cusotmerid'] = input_file['cusotmerid'].astype(str)
input_file['cusotmerid'] = np.select([input_file['cusotmerid'].apply(lambda x: len(x) == 8),
                                     input_file['cusotmerid'].apply(lambda x: len(x) == 9)],
                                     [input_file['cusotmerid'].str[0:2] + '-' + input_file['cusotmerid'].str[2:8],
                                     'K' + '-' + input_file['cusotmerid'].str[0:3] + '-' + input_file['cusotmerid'].str[3:9]],
                                      input_file['cusotmerid'])
input_file

    id  cusotmerid
0   1   89-898988
1   2   K-898-989889
```

It may be easier to break the `np.select` statement down into conditions and results. The 3 parameters I pass are conditions, results, and default value if no conditions are met.

```
input_file['cusotmerid'] = input_file['cusotmerid'].astype(str)

c1 = input_file['cusotmerid'].apply(lambda x: len(x) == 8)
c2 = input_file['cusotmerid'].apply(lambda x: len(x) == 9)

conditions = [c1, c2]

r1 = input_file['cusotmerid'].str[0:2] + '-' + input_file['cusotmerid'].str[2:8]
r2 = 'K' + '-' + input_file['cusotmerid'].str[0:3] + '-' + input_file['cusotmerid'].str[3:9]

results = [r1,r2]

input_file['cusotmerid'] = np.select(conditions, results, input_file['cusotmerid'])
input_file

    id  cusotmerid
0   1   89-898988
1   2   K-898-989889
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do something like this.

You can use `pd.Series.map` with `len` built-in to find out the length of the column value. With that you can determine how to assign the value.

Using `astype(str)` converts the numeric value to string so you can do string concatenation.

```
input_file.loc[input_file['cusotmerid'].astype(str).map(len) == 8, 'new_customer_id'] = input_file['cusotmerid'].astype(str).str[:2]+ '-' + input_file['cusotmerid'].astype(str).str[2:]

input_file.loc[input_file['cusotmerid'].astype(str).map(len) == 9, 'new_customer_id'] = 'K-' + input_file['cusotmerid'].astype(str).str[:3] + '-' + input_file['cusotmerid'].astype(str).str[3:]
```

This should take are of the new value assignments.

The output of this is:

```
   cusotmerid new_customer_id
0    89898988       89-898988
1   898989889    K-898-989889
```

Comment: I use `.apply(lambda x: len(x) ==` all of the time. `.map(len)` is MUCH better. + 1

Comment: `apply()` is a bit slower than inbuilt functions. so i try to use what's already available.

Comment: exactly, I wasn't aware of this one. Apply should be a last resort if there are no available methods.